# C# DataGridView Event to Catch When Cell (ReadOnly) Value has been changed by user

Tags: events, datagridview, cell

I have a Winforms app written in C#.

In DataGridView, I have set a column(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) called 'Name' to ReadOnly = true.

When the user right click on a Cell of the 'Name' column -> Display a form to set a value -> I want the application to know: Cell's value of the 'Name' column has been changed.

I have tried many events but can not do, such as CellEndEdit, CellValueChanged

I'm only interested in catching user changes to data in the 'Plan' column where ReadOnly = true.

Which is the best event to use for this?
I attach information as below:

①　[Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU8vz.png)

②　[Source Code](http://www.mediafire.com/download/sg71i8sqgzy959c/formStudent4.zip)

Comment: I don't really get you, if it's ReadOnly, how can it be user-changed ?

Comment: The user changes through form. I've added pictures description and source code. Please confirm! Thank you!

Comment: Compare the value of the textbox after the click on the OK button with the value of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CellEndEdit` and `CellValueChanged` properties only work when the user changes manually the content of the DataGridView. What you have to do is just to read the value of the TextBox in the Set_Value_Of_Name form and compare it with the value of the DataGridView cell.

Add the following line :

```
btnOK.Click += (senderq, eq) =>
{
  frmValueOfName.Close();
  result = true;

  //Add this line
  if (txtValue.Text != dataGridView[currentMouseOverCol,currentMouseOverRow].Value.ToString())
  {
       MessageBox.Show("Value has been changed!");
  }
};
```

Comment: In the main form, what does the event use?

Comment: Thank you! I'll try

Comment: Ryan B : It has run well! Thank you!
Besides I have problems like the article below, do you know? Please help me! Thanks!
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977969/c-sharp-how-to-filter-list-data-into-datagridview-using-datetimepicker]